# Another thread is created after run method of thread finishes

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, generated

I have a class extending Thread class as follows.

```
public class RemoteDataSynchTaskProcessor extends Thread {
private GDRType taskGDR;

public RemoteDataSynchTaskProcessor(GDRType taskGDR) {
    this.taskGDR = taskGDR;
}

private void execute() {

    try {
        try {

            RemoteClient.runDataSynchTask(taskGDR);

        } catch (RemoteException re) {
            //.....
        } catch (NotBoundException e) {
            //......
        }
        processResult(false, "Success");
    } catch (DTSException de) {
    //....
    }

}

public void run() {
    Observer.incrementNumOfDataSyncyProcessor();

    try {
        execute();
    } finally {
        Observer.decrementNumOfDataSynchProcessor();
    }
}
```

After this thread's execution is over there appears another thread named: Thread [pool-34-thread-1] (Running)

I have no idea why this thread appears and never terminates, and i end up with thousands of threads after a couple of day with pool number increasing every time ( e.g. Thread [pool-2500-thread-1])

If if debug and suspend execution of these generated threads, the stack is as follows:

```
Thread [pool-1-thread-1] (Suspended)    
Unsafe.park(boolean, long) line: not available [native method]  
LockSupport.park(Object) line: 156  
AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await() line: 1987   
LinkedBlockingQueue<E>.take() line: 399 
ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask() line: 947  
ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() line: 907   
Thread.run() line: 662
```

What are these threads, how can i get rid of them ?

**EDIT**: Seems like it has something to do with closed source thread pooling lib i am using (judging by the comments asking about executor service).

I use a library that provides ThreadPool capability. This is how i create a pool at the beginning of application startup.

```
    ThreadPool fetcherPool = new ThreadPool("TASK_FETCHER", ConfigParams.minimumTaskFetcherCount, ConfigParams.maximumTaskFetcherCount, new TaskFetcher());
```

ThreadPool.java seems to be extending Java's ThreadGroup class, and ThreadFetcher is as follows, which actually triggers the thread.

```
public class TaskFetcher extends PooledMessageWorker //Pooled Message Worker extends ReacreatableThread

public void run() {
    Observer.incrementNumOfTaskFetcher();
    try {
        while (true) {
            try {
                if (Observer.isShutdowned()) {
                    break;
                }
                ControllerUtil.getInstance().waitIfPaused();

                ESDRType task = (ESDRType) TaskHandler.getTask();
                if (task != null) {
                    trigger(task);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LogUtil.error(logger, e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
    } finally {
        Observer.decrementNumOfTaskFetcher();
    }
}


private void trigger(ESDRType task) {
    try {
        GDRType[] messages = createMessages(esdr);
    for (GDRType message : messages) {
        RemoteDataSynchTaskProcessor remoteCDCMTaskProcessor = new      RemoteDataSynchTaskProcessor(message);
        remoteCDCMTaskProcessor.start(); //This thread causes a new thread appear after execution finishes
        LogUtil.debug(logger, "[distributeMessage()] [Message: ", message, "]... [OK]");    
    }
    } catch (DTSException exception) {
    // Logging stuff
    }
}
```

}

Comment: How do you create your `ExecutorService`?

Comment: ... and how do you _use_ said ExecutorService, because it isn't shown anywhere in the current code.

Comment: I have edited my post accordingly, @biziclop

Comment: @jtahlborn edited my post accordingly

Comment: what is RecreatableThread?  also, how do you _use_ the executors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry everyone, seems like it has nothing to do with that ThreadPool or RemoteDataSynchTaskProcessor.

I havent noticed another ExecutorService is created in a method that is called  by ProcessResults() method in RemoteDataSynchTaskProcessor. And executor server is not shutdown after its job is down. My bad.

So if anyone has a problem like this one with unexplained thrad occurrences, check your code twice :D Look for the problem somewhere else :P

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you must you the closed-source 3rd party ThreadPool library?  If not, make `RemoteDataSynchTaskProcessor` a `Runnable` (BTW, I always prefer extending/implementing `Runnable` to extending `Thread`) and try using it with an `ExecutorService`.

Actually, even if you must use the 3rd party library, I'd try this for debugging.  You might narrow down where the issue is.

Comment: I will use ExecutorService and see the result, will share results and accept your answer if the lib i use is the problem.

Btw any particular reason why you prefer Runnable over Thread ?

Comment: ExecutorService (and similar) work with runnables/Callables, nopt threads.  :-)

Comment: Runnable is preferable because it decouples the _what_ from the _how._ For example, your Thread pool may reuse existing Threads to run different tasks to avoid the creation overhead. If you give it three Runnables it can use the same thread for all three, one after the other. If you have three Threads it *has* to create all three.